# How to get django model relations using JSON?

Tags: django, json, django-rest-framework

I had no idea how to structure an accurate title for this question, but I did my best so please bear with me.

I am working on a app for my hockey team that consists of a django app and an mobile app that communicates with the django app using JSON (django-rest-framework). However, one problem I am struggeling with figuring out how to solve is as follows:

You create a user (using Token Authentication), and then you create a player and/or a manager.

However, what I am struggling with is what to do when an existing user logs in. How do I check whether or not there is a player or manager associated with that user? When I log in, all I get in return from the rest framework is that user's authentication token, so from a programming perspective, I have no clue what user it actually is since I dont have the user's Id. Even if I did, how can I look up players by anything other than their Id? Currently the only idea I have is to grab all players and loop through them to find one with the same email address as the user currently signed in has.

Hope this made some degree of sense!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a question about JSON.

Surely the token is associated with a user ID? I don't use django-rest-framework, but [the documentation for TokenAuthentication](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#tokenauthentication) is pretty clear that once the user logs in with their token, you'll get a normal `auth.User` instance in `request.user` just like you would with a standard web-based login.

Your second question is probably made irrelevant by that, but even so, you can always query by an email address, without needing to loop through:

```
Manager.objects.get(email=my_email_address)
```

Again this is standard Django querying - if you're not familiar with that syntax, you should do the Django tutorial.

Of course, since you have a User already, you can do a more efficient foreign key lookup:

```
Manager.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

or even

```
request.user.manager
```

(assuming you have a one-to-one relationship from User to Manager - it would have been helpful to see your models).

Comment: Thanks! However, I do think my issue is with JSON as I think I have a solid understanding of Django as far as playing with Python goes. However, since my mobile app only communicates with the Django app using JSON (which I dont have much experience with), its not clear to me how to properly query for the information I am after. So far I have only grabbed the JSON response messages which have usually given me what I needed and worked with that, but since I only get the auth token back when logging in, I dont really know much about the user. Again, Im probably missing some essential knowledge..

Comment: But you wouldn't do that on the client, surely? You rely on the server knowing who the user is, and querying the database and returning the data appropriately. That's the whole point of the client-server separation. You'll need to write custom views on the server side to return the data you need.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense and I guess I need to go back to the drawing board and create some sensible views to help me get what I need. Thank you.